# GWT + Struts2 vs DOJO + Struts2

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, struts2, dojo

We are creating a web application that will be hosted on tomcat and uses quite a few AJAX components.

Does anyone give any suggestion on which toolkit to use. I am looking for something that is easier to use and integrate with struts2. Performance is also a highly desirable aspect.

As such, I am open to any suggestions that anyone might have:
1) Struts with DOJO
2) Struts with GWT 
3) GWT alone

What are the pros and cons of each of these technology fusion. If possible please include some examples/links that you might have.

Please help !

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I guess the obvious: with GWT you can do everything in Java and not worry too much about maintaining Javascript code, isn't much of a concern in your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT allows to code all the client side behavior using Java instead of Javascript, this is great if you are create a web application, on the other hand if you are creating a web site, with some ajax and dynamic behavior sprinkled in it, then I think GWT is overkill and will make your site bloated because it will have to reload all the GWT code every time the user jumps from one page to the other.

Dojo is a great framework and it will allow you to create both web apps and web sites, but it requires you have a team of developers with good Javascript skills which may o may not be an issue for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I have one more question, if you know, which framework has better integrity with struts2 ?

Comment: I think they can both integrate well with struts, as they both can 'talk' to the server well by passing JSON back and forth. May be GWT might an advantage because you can probably reuse your Model Objects and let GWT serialized them back and forth from Struts. One thing to note is that with GWT it is recommended to *not* reload the page on every user action therefore the Struts underpinning would work more like services.

Answer (score 1):

I will not advice to use GWT with Struts. GWT provides its own UI elements/components/widgets tied with AJAX behavior in form of Java (from source code perspective). On the other hand, struts has a separate UI component in form of JSPs, and DOJO is javascript based AJAX framework.

If you have high concentration of AJAX behavior in your UI elements, use GWT alone with some good server side technology e.g. Spring+Hibernate.

If AJAX behavior is required in fewer UI elements, use Struts+DOJO combination. Here also, you can leverage same server side technologies e.g. Spring+Hibernate.

Some more inputs regarding GWT usage and it's limitations are documented in my blog: http://yogendrakrsingh.blogspot.ca/2010/03/google-web-toolkit-gwt-uses-and.html